# Confusions regarding expressions of transfer functions of ideal integrator and ideal differentiator?

Tags: transfer-function, poles-zeros

The ideal integrator has differentiator has transfer function **H(s)= -1/RCs** while ideal differentiator has transfer function **H(s)= -RCs**

It is often said regarding above integrator that it has a zero at infinity similarly it is often said regarding above differentiator that it has a pole at infinity

But as far as given expressions of transfer functions are concerned, i am unable to find/observe any pole in transfer function of differentiator (It has only 1 in denominator) while also i am unable to find/observe any zero in transfer function of differentiator(It has only 1 in numerator)

Is it some thing similar to phenomena that is called pole zero cancellation?

Comment: Why the minus signs and the constant $RC$?

Answer (score 1):

The matter is actually very simple. If a transfer function $H(s)$ satisfies

$$\lim_{s\to\infty}H(s)=0\tag{1}$$

we say that it has a zero at infinity. This is the case for the ideal integrator.

If $H(s)$ satisfies

$$\lim_{s\to\infty}H(s)=\infty\tag{2}$$

it has a pole at infinity, which is the case for the ideal differentiator.

If we include poles and zeros at infinity, the number of poles of a (rational) transfer function always equals its number of zeros.